# Huygens’s principle

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

On the application of Huygens’s principle with an incident wavefront on the mirror, we see that wavelets are emitted at each point as shown.

My question is how can the direction of propagation of the reflected wavefront be perpendicular to the incident wavefront (as shown by the downward-pointing arrows in the image).

[image]

The tangent to these reflected wavelets shows that the new wavefront has been reflected at an angle equal to the incident angle, but my question is how can it be perpendicular to the incident wavefront.

Comment: its downward only after the wavefront bounces off the mirror

Comment: rewrite your question to include; My question is .................  Be specific and clear.  this may get it off hold and you will get some answers.

Comment: @user45664 okey thanks

Comment: also this figure is confusing--if you google huygens principle and look at the images i think you will find better ones (for a plane wave being reflected off a 45 degree mirror).

Comment: unfortunately the question still needs rewording--i still can not understand it. are you asking how there results a plane wave traveling downward after the reflection?